# How can i set some names to be able to type a command in roblox to kill other people

Tags: roblox

i am making a tycoon that's getting around and i want admin powers, that reminds me of Austin powers. anyways, i need something to let me type :kill [name] or something like that to be able to kill anybody! please help, i only found 1 answer to some one else who asked this but i couldn't understand, i tried to find right syntax, i couldn't figure it out.

I found this though, but it only does it for that person, maybe something like kill/..player.Name?

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(player) --this gets the player that connected
player.Chatted:connect(function(message) --this function executes when the player type into chat
--commands are here
if player.Name == "AlexanderYar" or player.Name == "nathancain" or player.Name == "block100000" then
    if message == "kill/me" then
        player.Character.Head:remove()
        end

    if message == "ff/me" then
        if player.Character:findFirstChild("ForceField") then
            player.Character.ForceField:Destroy()
        end

        Instance.new("ForceField").Parent = player.Character
        end

    if message == "unff/me" then 
        if player.Character:findFirstChild("ForceField") then
            player.Character.ForceField:Destroy()
            end
        end
    end
end)
end)
```

Comment: please give me a block of code that has the right syntax when say kill/..player.name

Answer (score 0):

**Original code was this:**

```
if message == "kill/me" then
    player.Character.Head:remove()
end
```

**Replace with this code:**

```
if string.sub(message,1,5) == "kill/" then
    local targetName = string.sub(message,6)
    if targetName == "me" or targetName == "Me" then
        player.Character.Head:Destroy()
    else
        for i,v in ipairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
            if string.lower(v.Name) == string.lower(targetName) and v.Character and v.Character:FindFirstChild("Head") then
                v.Character.Head:Destroy()
            end
        end
    end
end
```

This should now work for killing other players!